# Would go vs would be going

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

> 1) She ***would go*** to the graduation ceremony if she had not broken her leg last week.
>
> 2) She ***would be going*** to the graduation ceremony if she had not broken her leg last week.

What is the difference in meaning ?

Comment: It's a matter of nuance. In practice (1) is probably less likely, but to my ear it carries stronger allusions to *volition, intention* (she *wanted* to go, but can't). (2) is more neutral on that point, and could feasibly be used even in contexts where she never wanted to go anyway (she might even think the broken leg was a [lucky break](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lucky_break), since it got her out of having to go).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is usually the case, the progressive places emphasis on the *unfolding action*.  The practical implications of that fact might become clearer if we talk about what situations might call for the progressive over the simple present.

Let's say we are students lined up to enter the hall where our graduation ceremony will take place *in a few minutes*. Our friend is not here because she has broken her leg. Which tense are we likely to choose?

> She **would be going** to graduation if she hadn't broken her leg.

Now, by way of contrast, let's say that we are students discussing the graduation ceremony which is to take place several weeks from now.  If is very doubtful that our friend will be there with us because she has just broken her leg quite badly. We know that she would like to attend but the nature of the injury was severe and she won't be ambulatory for quite a long time.

> She **would go** to graduation if she hadn't broken her leg so badly.

*Would go* places emphasis on the *prospective* aspect.

P.S. Please note that I say "are we *likely* to choose".  Both of these forms are grammatical. The speaker could frame the statement in either way, reflecting their thought and perspective at that moment.